# KODAK Film camera (M35) not advancing my film correctly

Tags: film, camera, kodak, film-cameras

My KODAK Film camera (M35) is not advancing my film correctly. I turn the film advance wheel and it moves but it doesn't stop to allow the shutter? I'm not sure how to make the shutter work again.

Comment: Some pictures of what's happening?

Comment: Possibly related? [kodak m35 advance wheel does not roll the film but when there is no film, the spool roll just fine](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/125298/15871) Perhaps your film is not actually advancing, thus not cocking the shutter?